# Is there a way to not have a from tag create a tab?

Tags: html, forms, button, paypal, shopping-cart

I am making a simple website with a shopping cart and I am using the Paypal "add to cart" button code:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" 
 method="post">

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="kin@kinskards.com">

<!-- Specify a PayPal Shopping Cart Add to Cart button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">

<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Birthday - Cake and Candle">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="3.95">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_addtocart_120x26.png"
alt="Add to Cart">
<img alt="" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
</form>
```

I also have a shopping cart logo on the upper right corner and I only want the cart to be accessible through clicking the logo. Is there any way to have the form send the data to the paypal shopping cart but not open the shopping cart tab/window?

Answer (score 0):

Change `target=paypal` to `target="_self"` : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_cart/#open-shopping-cart-in-the-merchant-window

Comment: I tried it but it just opens up the paypal shopping cart in the same tab. I don't want it to open up the paypal shopping cart at all when you click the button. i just want it to send the data to the shopping cart that 1 item has been added, then when I click the cart logo it opens up the paypal shopping cart.

Comment: I see. That doesn't seem possible using only PayPal. They specifically say that adding an item to their cart will direct the customer to the cart. You can configure the button Continue Shopping: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_cart/#continue-shopping-on-the-current-merchant-web-page A workaround would be to implement your own cart (or use a cart library) and push your cart info into PayPal's form.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.